# Where to put CSS rules in ASCX custom control?

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I'm new to working in ASP.NET but I'm developing a custom control that has a multi view control inside it that displays a bunch of different stuff. Some of it is displayed using JQuery UI elements like tabs and accordians which will have quite a bit of customisation.

Since I'm going to have a lot of CSS rules that apply only to the elements inside the custom control (not to the rest of our web site), I'm wondering where to put the CSS style rules.

I'd normally just put a style sheet somewhere in the site root and reference it from there. But as I play around with ASP.NET, I get the feeling that I should be putting all my code (including CSS, JS, etc) inside the custom control itself. This feels more "programmy", keeping everything together.

Can anyone adivse how I should be doing this? What's the best practice for web development in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the control you are creating is in a *separate assembly*, you can embed the CSS files inside the assembly to make it reusable and create a *direct link to these files from your control*, then in your control you will register them to be rendered as `link` tags in your page

Note: Remember that you need to mark the CSS file in your assembly as an *Embedded Resource*

Just select your file | then proeprties and change its *Build Action* property and set it to: *embedded Resource*

[image]

In the following code:

- `AjaxEnabled.Web.UI` represents the namespace of your assembly
- `DefaultStyle.css` represents the embedded CSS file name

The following code sample shows the steps needed: (in your custom server control)

```
[assembly: WebResource("AjaxEnabled.Web.UI.DefaultStyle.css", "text/css")]

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (this.Page.Header != null)
        {
            if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("defaultCss"))
            {
                var link = new HtmlLink();

                link.Href = this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(
                    typeof(YourControlType),
                    "AjaxEnabled.Web.UI.DefaultStyle.css"
                );
                link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

                this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(Page),
                    "defaultCss",
                    string.Empty
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to add an instance of the `ScriptManager` control in your page containing your custom controls

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm"/>
```

And in your ASPX page you need to mark the `header` section as a server control

```
<head runat="server">
```

---

The following code:

```
link.Href = this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(
                typeof(YourControlType),
                "AjaxEnabled.Web.UI.DefaultStyle.css");
```

Renders a link *directly to the CSS file embedded in the assembly*

---

This condition:

```
if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("defaultCss"))
...
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                        typeof(Page),
                        "defaultCss",
                        string.Empty
                    );
```

ensures that the CSS is rendered only once in the page, even if you drop more than one instances of your control

Comment: Out of interest, why would that require a separate assembly?

Comment: It is only required if you want to fully encapsulate your styles in the control. If you do it, then you can simply share your ddl containing your control and the CSS files iwll be shared because they will be embedded in the assembly. However this is not required, if you only plan to use your controls in one site. I will update the answer to show the code needed to use resources embedded in an assembly

Comment: initially, I would not be distributing the code. But it's a plugin for a commercial CMS, so once I'm happy with it, I think I'll embrace this solution so we can distribute the complete code as a package for other people to use. Thanks for a comprehensive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put in the page you are using.

Why?

1. In case of multiple controls on the page, if you apply style/js to the usercontrol without referencing to an external stylesheet or script, you will see a lot of CSS/js code being repeated for each individual control.
2. Better management of the code.
3. The control of the CSS is with the page and not the control itself, so the same control can be used for multiple pages, which may need different styling.

Comment: _In case of multiple controls on the page, if you apply style to the usercontrol, you will see a lot of CSS code being repeated on the controls._ **That's not true, you can control to just render one CSS link**

Comment: The OP in his question says "I get the feeling that I should be putting all my code (including CSS, JS, etc) inside the custom control itself". That means he is not thinking about referencing.