# Can we add style sheet to ascx?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an ascx control created that has various asp controls in it.Now, I want to attach a style sheet with properties to it. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes attach it to your `aspx` page in which you are going to use the `UserControl` it will use the stylesheet.

Comment: Rahul, You mean to say the style sheet to be attached to the aspx that is using the ascx?

Comment: This question would help you to solve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445106/where-to-put-css-rules-in-ascx-custom-control

Comment: @ANSHAA - `UserControl` is nothing but a collection of reusable controls which we use on a page. So whatever style you will define on you page will automatically apply to the controls inside your user control also.